# Git merge overwrites rather than giving conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm trying to merge two repositories. But whenever I merge, it should give conflict in sample.txt file rather that overwriting the same. Steps followed are in attached image.Git version is : 2.7.4
Is the process right? if yes, the why don't I get conflicts?

[image: repro]

[Full-size image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4I9J.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour, this use case should not lead to a conflict. There is no “real” merging done, since the changes from the branch can be simply applied to `master` as if the other branch never existed (this is called a “fast-forward merge”). Before merge:

```
--A--B <-- master
      \
       C--D <-- branch
```

After merge:

```
--A--B--C--D <-- master
```

If you wanted to see a conflict, you would have to create a history like this:

```
--A--B--D <-- master
      \
       C--E <-- branch
```

Now if the commit D “touches the same lines” as C and E, there could be a conflict when you try to merge back to master.